# Byte order in AES-CMAC test code

Tags: aes, test-vectors, cmac

I'm looking at the [AES-CMAC RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4493) and I found somehow counter-intuitive the way [test vectors](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4493#section-4) are used in the [test code](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4493#appendix-A).

Let's look at the key `K`

`K      2b7e1516 28aed2a6 abf71588 09cf4f3c`

The least significant octet is `0x3c`, right? If this is true, why it becomes `key[15]` and not `key[0]` in the test code?

```
 unsigned char key[16] = {
     0x2b, 0x7e, 0x15, 0x16, 0x28, 0xae, 0xd2, 0xa6,
     0xab, 0xf7, 0x15, 0x88, 0x09, 0xcf, 0x4f, 0x3c
 };
```

Comment: Have you checked the _notations and conventions_ section of the [AES specification](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.197.pdf#page=11)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keys for AES are not numbers; they are defined as bits / octets (or bytes). They therefore do not have a "least significant octet", they just consist of octets. So the same order from lowest index (left) to highest index (right) is being used.

As common the bits are indexed from right to left though; this is probably due to humans having some trouble converting hexadecimal digits otherwise. It just shows that humans are terrible at thinking in little endian.

The exact ordering is specified in the [AES specification](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.197.pdf#page=11) [as mentioned by fgrieu int he comments](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/86448/byte-order-in-aes-cmac-test-code/86449#comment189442_86448).

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. The key of the example is just a sequence of 128 bits that starts with 00101011 and ends with 00111100, so when this is represented as an array of 16 bytes, the first byte key[0] is set to be 00101011, which is now intuitive. Thanks!